# getting a variable from one class to another

Tags: python-3.x, class

this is one class in my program and i would like to get the variable profile out of this class and use it in another class

```
class LoginPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        self.Logo = PhotoImage(file = "Logo.gif")

        def Log_in():

            with sqlite3.connect("UserInfo.db") as db:
                cursor = db.cursor()


            user = (self.UserEntry.get())
            Pass = (self.PassEntry.get())

            if user == "" or Pass == "":
                msg = MsgBox("", "Make sure to fill all the boxes\nPlease try again")
                msg.label['font'] = 'Verdana 10'
                msg.button['text'] = 'Close'
                msg.button.pack(expand = True)

            else:

                dictionary = {}
                cursor.execute("SELECT username, password FROM users")
                for pword in cursor.fetchall():
                    (key ,val) = tuple(pword)
                    dictionary[str(key)] = val



                if user in dictionary:
                    if dictionary[user] == Pass:

                        sql = '''SELECT userID FROM users WHERE username = ?'''
                        cursor.execute(sql, (user,))

                        ***profile = cursor.fetchall()***

                        controller.show_frame(HomePage)
                        self.UserEntry.delete(0, 'end')
                        self.PassEntry.delete(0, 'end')

                    else:
                        messagebox.showinfo("", "Enter the correct password")
                        self.PassEntry.delete(0, 'end')

        self.logo = tk.Label(self, image = self.Logo)

        self.User = tk.Label(self, text = "User Name:").place(x = 72, y = 130)
        self.Pass = tk.Label(self, text = "Password:").place(x = 80, y = 155)

        self.UserEntry = Entry(self)

        self.PassEntry = Entry(self, show = '*')

        self.login = ttk.Button(self, text = "Login", command = Log_in)
        self.signup = ttk.Button(self, text = "Create account",
                                 command = lambda:controller.show_frame(SignUp))

        self.UserEntry.place(width = 100, height = 20, x = 140, y = 130)
        self.PassEntry.place(width = 100, height = 20, x = 140, y = 155)
        self.login.place(x = 80, y = 180)
        self.signup.place(x = 160, y = 180)
        self.logo.place(x = 110, y = 20)
```

below is the class that i would like to get the variable profile into.

```
class AddJob(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        def dbAddJob():


            JobT = self.Jt.get("1.0", 'end').rstrip('\n')
            JobD = self.Jd.get("1.0", 'end').rstrip('\n')

            with sqlite3.connect("UserInfo.db") as db:
                cursor = db.cursor()

            if JobT == "" or JobD == "":
                messagebox.showinfo("Invalid","please fill in the boxes or cancel") 
            else:
                aj = messagebox.askokcancel("Continue", "Job added click ok to continue\nor cancel or change what you have added")
                if aj == True:
                    cursor.execute("""
                    INSERT INTO jobs (jobtitle, jobdescript)
                    VALUES (?, ?)
                    """, (JobT, JobD))
                    db.commit()
                    self.Jt.delete('1.0', END)
                    self.Jd.delete('1.0', END)

                    controller.show_frame(JobsPage)

            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM jobs")
            print(cursor.fetchall())

        MapPageCanvas = Canvas(self, width = 320, height = 568)
        MapPageCanvas.pack()

        TopBar = MapPageCanvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 320, 50,
                                                fill = 'light grey')
        Home = MapPageCanvas.create_text((100, 25),
                                         text = "Add a Job",
                                         font = HOME_FONT)

        MenuButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Back",
                            command = lambda:controller.show_frame(JobsPage)).place(height = 40, width = 40, x = 5, y = 5)

        self.Addjobbutton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Add",
                                 command = dbAddJob).place(width = 60, height = 30, x = 90, y = 520)

        self.Cancel = ttk.Button(self, text = "cancel",
                                command = lambda:controller.show_frame(JobsPage)).place(width = 60, height = 30, x = 170, y = 520)

        self.Jt = ScrolledText(self)
        self.Jd = ScrolledText(self)

        self.Jt.place(height = 30, width = 310, x = 5, y = 60)
        self.Jd.place(height = 400, width = 310, x = 5, y = 100)
```

it would be much appreciated if anyone could give me some advice as i have been having trouble with this for a while

Comment: Could make a function inside the class which would return the profile. Then make a variable in the main calling to that function and then you should be able to use that anywhere in your program.

Comment: If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: could you possible show me how as i am having trouble understanding your wording

Comment: Ye, the answer below should work fine. assign the result of g function to a variable and then you can access that variable anywhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Read the comments in the code and it should be straight forward.
If still any questions, then please ask.

```
class LoginPage():

    def __init__(self):
        # Create empty variable
        self.profile = ""

    def Log_in(self):
        # Set profile value
        self.profile = "Hello World!"

    def returnProfile(self):
        # return profile
        return self.profile

# Create Object
page = LoginPage()

# Return Profile Data
profile = page.returnProfile()

print(profile)
// Hello World!
```

More about OOP here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Comment: absolutely no need for `returnProfile` function. just use `my_object.profile`